# Applying ～すればするほど (and its variants) to various part of speech

Tags: grammar, adjectives

## Verbs

> 気にしなければ気にしないほど、息子がもっと煩くなる。The more I ignore him, the more noisy he is.

## Adjectives (i adjectives)

> 牛乳は入れた砂糖が多ければ多いほど、甘くなる。The more sugar you pour into the milk, the sweeter it becomes.

## Adjectival Nouns (na adjectives)

> 俳優は有名ならば有名なほど、給料が高くなる。The more famous an actor is, the higher his salary becomes.

## Question

Now I want to apply this grammar to an adverb よく (often) or しばしば (often). The sentence I want to say is

> A: The more often you wash clothes with bleach, the quicker its fabric becomes fragile.
>
> A: 服は、ブリーチで洗うのが頻繁ならば頻繁なほど、早く脆くなる。

Here I was forced to use adjectival noun　頻繁 rather than よく (often) or しばしば (often)。

Is it possible to use this grammar with an adverb? If yes, how to apply it to my sentence A above?

Comment: Are you sure about the first translation? 気にする = "to care", not "to ignore".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot apply this grammar directly to an adverb because adverbs don't conjugate to ば/れば. But you can repeat the verb itself.

> - 牛乳は砂糖を多く入れれば入れるほど甘くなる。
> - 俳優は有名であればあるほど給料が高くなる。
> - 服はブリーチで頻繁に洗えば洗うほど早く脆くなる。
> - 服はブリーチでよく洗えば洗うほど早く脆くなる。

But unlike English *often*, しばしば doesn't work very well with this pattern anyway, probably due to the same reason why "The more sometimes you wash clothes ～" is not used in English.

---

By the way, your first sentence needs some improvement, too. First, 煩わしい means *annoying* rather than *noisy*. If 煩わしい is what you really mean to say, the sentence needs ～ようにする ("try to ～") and "感じる ("feel"), because this sentence is subjective and the speaker is failing to ignore him after all.

> - 気にしないようにすればするほど、息子がもっと煩わしく感じる。
>     The more I try to ignore my son, the more I am annoyed by him.
> - 無視すればするほど、息子がもっとうるさくなる。
>     The more I ignore my son, the more he becomes noisy.

Comment: Is 牛乳は入れた砂糖が多ければ多いほど、甘くなる not natural?

Comment: Yes, perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, constructions like "the more... the more..." are used much more frequently in English than in Japanese. Perhaps a more natural way of conveying the message of your last sentence would be something like...

> ブリーチで洗うことによって繊維が破れやすくなります。

However, if you would like to use the「すればするほど」construction, I would suggest something like...

> ブリーチで洗えば洗うほど繊維が破れやすくなります。

For your other examples I would suggest the following:

### Verbs

- 無視**されればされるほど**、もっとうるさくなる。
  The more he is ignored, the more noisy he becomes.
- 運動**すればするほど**、体が疲れる。
  The more you drive the more tired you get.
- トーストはバターを**塗れば塗るほど**、美味しい。
  Toast tastes better the more butter you spread on it.

### Adjectives (i adjectives)

- 砂糖が**多ければ多いほど**、甘くなる。
  The more sugar there is, the sweeter it becomes.
- 人口が**少なければ少ないほど**、税収が下がる。
  The lower the population, the lower the tax revenue.

### Adjectival Nouns (na adjectives)

- 俳優は有名**であればあるほど**、給料が高くなる。
  The more famous an actor is, the higher his salary becomes.
- 冷静**であればあるほど**、喧嘩を避けられる。
  The calmer you are, the easier it will be to avoid fights.